# Can't run executable in a remote computer using .bat file

Tags: batch-file, network-programming, exe

I have this test.bat file in my computer:

```
echo "pre"
systeminfo
echo "post"
```

When I try running it in a remote computer using this command it returns an error 255.

```
paexec \\<remote ip> -u <machine username> -p <machine password> -s -c -f -csrc "<path where the test.bat>\test.bat" test.bat
```

But when I run systeminfo directly in a command prompt using this command it works:

```
paexec \\<remote ip> -u <machine username> -p <machine password> systeminfo
```

What could be it's caused?
I tried searching the error 255 and I can't find the answer what I am looking for. 

**"systeminfo"** is just an example, I tried another programs like ipconfig, shutdown or any other executable installed in the remote computer and still it returns error 255. 

*"I am using an **Administrator** account for this test."*

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) instead

```
psexec -s \\REMOTE_MACHINE "\\my-network-location\test.bat"
```

This will display the info of the remote machine:

```
Host Name:                 REMOTE_MACHINE
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
OS Version:                6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Additional/Backup Domain Controller
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

---

Sidenote: `systeminfo` can also specify a remote machine:

Example:

```
systeminfo /S remote-machine
```

If you need to specify user context:

```
systeminfo /S remote-machine /U mydomain\username /P password
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but as I said systeminfo is just an example. My problem is I can't run any executable installed in a remote computer using a batch file. Sorry if I am not clear of what my problem is.

Comment: @xerxesjunemark updated answer to something I just tested.  I was going to suggest `psexec`, but i saw you were using a different tool.  At the end of the day, `psexec` is probably going to work the best.  (I left the note about `systeminfo` in case someone else comes across the post)

Comment: thanks, I tried it but the same error was returned. And I don't want to use another tool **if possible**. Another scenario is, this code is working on another remote computer and there is only one remote computer that this code never works.

Comment: Please add `echo %COMPUTERNAME%` into the batch file and report back if it's the remote computer or the local computer.  This at least tells us the context of the running batch

Comment: @xerxesjunemark also, you say you're running an administrator account.  Is this on the local machine or the remote machine ?

Comment: I think there is something that blocking my .bat file to run an executable in remote computer.

Comment: It's the remote machine account that I'm using.

Comment: @xerxesjunemark I agree.  Check the permissions on the batch file and just for a test give `everyone` full control.  Also, just taking a stab in the dark here because I've never had this issue, but some users report error 255 - extended attributes when trying to run certain executables if their sound scheme is not set to default: https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-the-extended-attributes-are-inconsistent-error-in-windows-10